# How to add a dot marker on the avatar image in HTML?

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I want to add a blue color dot marker on right bottom of an avatar img, the result should be looks like as below.

```
<avatar>
    <img [src]="item.profilepic"/>
</avatar>
```

[image]

Is it possible to do that in HTML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You can do it like this:

```css
.avatar {
    height: 256px;
    width: 256px;
    position: absolute;
}
.dot {
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background: blue;
    position: absolute;
    right: 25px;
    bottom: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="avatar">
    <img src="http://aux2.iconspalace.com/uploads/smile-icon-256.png">
    <div class="dot"></div>
</div>
```

With Ionic tags it looks like this:

**HTML**

```
<ion-avatar>
    <img src="http://aux2.iconspalace.com/uploads/smile-icon-256.png"/>
    <div class="dot"></div>
</ion-avatar>
```

**CSS**

```
ion-avatar {
  height: 256px;
  width: 256px;
  position: absolute;
}
.dot {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  right: 25px;
  bottom: 25px;
}
```

[image]